# Binary tree from general tree

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-tree, knockout.js

I have a tree structure that has a node with a parent ID (unlimited child nodes). For display purposes I need this tree structure as a binary tree. How I do this is at each level nodes are grouped into a single node based upon a condition. When a node is selected its children are then displayed. Example:

[image: N-Ary tree]

The green is when the condition is `true` and red is `false`

[image: BTree]

B, C have been grouped into the left node and D, E are on the right based on their conditions.

**QUESTION:** I'm using KnockoutJS to display my tree and I need to be able to perform normal tree operations like getting a node based on its ID, inserting node(s) removing node(s). This is the structure I have. Is there a better structure/way of doing this?

```
var tree = [
    { groupNodeId: "A", childNodes: [
        { nodeId: "A", childGroupNodes: [
            { groupNodeId: "B", condition: true, childNodes: [
                { nodeId: "B", childGroupNodes: []},
                { nodeId: "C", childGroupNodes: []}
            ]},
            { groupNodeId: "D", condition: false, childNodes: [
                { nodeId: "D", childGroupNodes: []},
                { nodeId: "E", childGroupNodes: []}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
];
```

Comment: Why are you using `childGroupNodes` and `groupNodeId` for the inserted nodes instead of continuing to use `childNodes` and `nodeId`? Also, if, for example, B and C each have a child whose `condition` is true, do you want those two nodes grouped together?

Comment: Also, I assume `condition: true` in groupNode `D` is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but assuming that:

1. You want to insert "groupNodes", not regular nodes, and that groupNodes can have unlimited children.
2. The original tree contains only regular nodes, not groupNodes.
3. All regular nodes have a nodeId, a condition set to true or false, and an array childNodes.
4. You don't want to create groupNodes that would have no children.

then here's your answer.

```
function binize(tree) {
  var left,right,t,u,
    stack=[tree];
  while(t=stack.pop()) {
    left=[];
    right=[];
    while(u=t.childNodes.pop()) {
      (u.condition?left:right).push(u);
      stack.push(u);
    }
    left.length&&t.childNodes.push({
      groupNodeId:left[0].nodeId,
      condition:true,
      childNodes:left
    });
    right.length&&t.childNodes.push({
      groupNodeId:right[0].nodeId,
      condition:false,
      childNodes:right
    });
  }
}
```

I tested it using this data structure (note that tree is the top level object, not an array containing it).

```
var tree={nodeId:'A',childNodes:[
  {nodeId:'B',condition:true,childNodes:[]},
  {nodeId:'C',condition:true,childNodes:[]},
  {nodeId:'D',condition:false,childNodes:[
    {nodeId:'F',condition:false,childNodes:[]},
    {nodeIf:'G',condition:false,childNodes:[]}
  ]},
  {nodeId:'E',condition:false,childNodes:[]}
]};
```

If I knew a little more about your tree then I might have taken a different approach. For example, if the tree isn't very deep then it might be more efficient (and of course cleaner) to dig through it recursively.

Also, I have never used KnockoutJS before, and have no idea what structures it likes. I just generated the structures you indicated; hopefully that will work.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll test this out tonight, but from my understanding now this maybe a nested set? or a binary tree that each node contains another binary tree

Comment: Well, it alternates modes, as your example does. So level 1 has the top-level node, and the next level is two groupNodes. The next level (the groupNodes' children) contains all the original children of the top node, and the next level contains 2 groupNodes per parent Node (if the group wouldn't be empty), and so on. That's what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yes it is, partly... This shows how to create my tree from a general tree but I want to know how to traverse my structure in an efficient way

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought you already had traversal functions that you wanted the tree to work with. But now you have to tell me some more - what exactly do you mean by traverse? Get a node by ID, or move down / up / across a certain distance? If you're looking for the efficiency of a binary tree then that means seeking nodes by their condition - eg, not "find the node with nodeId A", but "find the node at true/true/false/true/false".

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding :P I thought about this and figured the groupNodes where the binary search tree and then each left and right contains the node(s). Is there no way to hash the id's of the nodes into the groupNode soI can have the binary search tree functionality work? or will I just have to traverse this as a general tree?

Comment: Ok, why don't you just tell me what you want the end result to be, and we'll work from there? It sounds to me like you want a tree of nodes with ids that are a string, and you want to be able to search by nodeId with the efficiency of a binary tree. Is that correct? Is that *everything* you want?

Comment: Ok, a few more questions. Does the id have to be a string, or could it be a number, or binary data? And am I correct to assume that you don't need groupNodes, you were just using them because you didn't know how else to group the nodes? And finally, is "condition" determined by the nodeId, or will it already be stored as part of the node?

Comment: The id can be anything, but I do need the group nodes for displaying the data in the DOM and it works nicely with KnockoutJS. I'm displaying it like the 2nd image in my question.

Comment: Ok, you're going to have to choose which type of tree you want. If you use groupNodes then the tree can't have the efficiency of a binary tree, because you still have to search each groupNode for the appropriate child. Additionally, how would the tree be structured if the original (non-binary) tree were four levels deep?

Comment: This is my dilemma, it would be very deep! I was also thinking about structuring it like { nodeId: 1, left: [{}, {}, {}], right: [{}, {}]} Would that make more sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6368/discussion-between-skier88-and-ryan)